# Unable to save dynamic action with clientId xx because the UIComponent cannot be found

Tags: css, jsf, bootsfaces

I use PrimeFaces and BootsFaces.

How do I fix this error?

> Feb 25, 2016 12:46:56 AM
>   com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl
>   logMissingResource WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource,
>   css/default/icons.css, from library, bsf

Comment: How can I reproduce this error? Can you upload a demo project, for example on GitHub? And what is the effect of the error? Is it only an error message, or are the icons really missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting the warning. For some reason it's trying to find the css file under default directory.
The final generated html file has good link:

```
<link href="/MoneyTracker-1.0-SNAPSHOT/faces/javax.faces.resource/css/icons.css?ln=bsf" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

When I copy file from `mavenResources/META-INF/resources/bsf/css/icons.css` to `mavenResources/META-INF/resources/bsf/css/default/icons.css` in the source of BootsFaces the warning goes away, but it is not the correct fix, I'm pretty sure.

That is, I think there is some problem in configuration of BootsFaces.

Comment: Read the comment in the question and please comment on that

Answer (score 0):

This is now a [known bug in BootsFaces 0.8.1](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/328) and was fixed in the [current 0.8.2 Snapshot](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/151), if you want to get rid of it.

**Edit:**
I just saw that the error message in the title differs from the one mentioned in the question.
For the warning in your title [there is a current issue as well](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/325). Generally this warning is harmless, but it's still annoying if it swamps your logs.
It should be partially fixed, but I could still observe it in the current snapshot. That said, we are working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to resolve this problem by converting JSF Managed/CDI bean from RequestScoped to Session Scoped. One can do this by following way,

```
@Named(value = "adminBean")
@SessionScoped
public class AdminBean implements Serializable{
...
}
```

Comment: Very illogical solutuo . Most likely this change forced a redeploy or something that fixed things